# Symfony 3 - Cannot implement FOSUser login on security because I use CAS authentication too

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I would like to add my FOSUser login method on my security.yml, because I use a authentication CAS, but I want an authentication with a login-form on my homepage (with User table on database which is different to User from CAS authentication)

So I configured my security.yml like this :

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    app:
       id: bes_auth.user_provider

firewalls:

    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
       # anonymous:    true

    public:
        pattern: ^accueil
        security: false
        anonymous: true

    main:
        logout_on_user_change: true
        pattern: ^/(admin|profile|packages|securiteInformatique|logout)
       # pattern: ^/(?!accueil)


        guard:
            authenticators:
                - app.security.login_form_authenticator:
                    check_path: fos_user_check_path

                - bes_auth.authenticator

        entry_point: Site\PagesBundle\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator


        logout:
            path:   deconnexion #nom de la route de déconnexion
            target: /
            success_handler: bes_auth.authenticator
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/accueil, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

But I've this error now :

> Invalid type for path
>   "security.firewalls.main.guard.authenticators.0". Expected scalar, but
>   got array.

It's about :

```
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - app.security.login_form_authenticator:
                    check_path: fos_user_check_path

                - bes_auth.authenticator

            entry_point: Site\PagesBundle\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
```

But I don't see what's wrong, can someone help me please ?

Comment: so it's written in the error - scalar needed. https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html#step-3-configure-the-authenticator

Answer (score 0):

just change your first Guard Authenticator without the option **check_path: fos_user_check_path** like this :

```html
...........

guard:
    authenticators:
        - app.security.login_form_authenticator
        - bes_auth.authenticator
```

if you want more explain, this is the document: [here](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/fosuserbundle/guard-authenticator)

thanks, I hope it's help you